# Read for specific text, and copy text from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to copy text from sheet1, over to sheet2, depending on the header.

`=IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A2:A40,(IF(Sheet1!B1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!B2:B40,(IF(Sheet1!C1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!C2:C40,(IF(Sheet1!D1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!D2:D40,(IF(Sheet1!E1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!E2:E40,(IF(Sheet1!F1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!F2:F40,(IF(Sheet1!G1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!G2:G40,"")))))))))))))`

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A2:A40,
  (IF(Sheet1!B1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!B2:B40,
    (IF(Sheet1!C1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!C2:C40,
      (IF(Sheet1!D1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!D2:D40,
        (IF(Sheet1!E1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!E2:E40,
          (IF(Sheet1!F1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!F2:F40,
            (IF(Sheet1!G1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!G2:G40
  ,"")))))))))))))
```

This unsightly mess is what I've got so far, but it only works about 57% of the time. I have no idea why.

Say for example, that the headers were Test1, Test2, Test3 etc, how could I make it so that excel reads sheet1 for the header Test1, and copies the column starting the cell beneath, and copies it over to whatever column Test1 is on in sheet2?

I have a rather basic understanding of excel formula, and even less of VBA, so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good task for `INDEX()`, by passing a 0 for one of the arguments you can state that you would like the whole column to be returned (or all rows of the matched column to be more precise):

`=INDEX(Sheet1!A2:G40,0,MATCH(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A1:G1,0))`

Without some example data and expected output I am unable to justify whether this is exactly what you are after though. Please feel free to provide more scope and leave me a comment, I will update my answer.

***EDIT:***

To get the results for the columns, you would assemble a lookup something like this:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$G$40,ROW()-1,MATCH(Sheet2!A$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$G$1,0))`

So that you index the data you want to be returned, then return the current row that you are on (offset by -1 as the data begins on the second row). The `MATCH()` at the end returns the position of the column title that matches `Sheet2!A$1`.

The `$$` is important here as the absolute referencing will stop the formula from changing when you drag it across the sheet (`Sheet2!A$1` will only update when dragged horizontally but not when dragged vertically)

Comment: Many thanks, and apologies for not being clear. Say I was trying to copy information over from sheet1, from A2 down, over to sheet2, in whichever column has the same header as was in sheet1, A1?

Comment: @C.Fsh Please see my edit and let me know if that helps.

Comment: That's absolutely perfect, thank you. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped